# ionice does not have any effect on un-synced writes (i.e. normal writes)?

Tags: linux, ionice

> When I dump a large MySQL database (its dump weighs around 10GB)
>   - it appears on the disk almost immediately, but then, later, when the kernel
>   decides to flush it to the disk, the server almost stalls and other IO requests
>   take a lot more time to complete even though mysqldump is run with ionice -c3,
>   so the use of ionice has no real effect.
>
> [Artem](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1814253454.3449.1382689853825.JavaMail.mail@webmail07/)

When you write data into the page cache, there is no field to store the IO priority.  So `ionice` will have no effect.  Do I have that right?

My latest kernel version is `4.18.16-200.fc28.x86_64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

> In theory, ionice allows you to prioritize a command's IO the way that nice(1) theoretically prioritizes its CPU usage. This would be a handy way to allow, say, a big but relatively important compile to grind away in the background without getting in the way of your interactive use of the machine.
>
> (Why yes, I do recompile Firefox from source every so often.)
>
> [...]
>
> The next problem is that even when running directly on a disk, `ionice` does nothing to de-prioritize asynchronous write IO. This is, well, most of the write IO that most programs will do. Ionice may slow down synchronous writes (I don't have a test program) and it definitely works for reads, but that's it.
>
> https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/IoniceNotes