# ext4 jbd2 and I/O priority

Tags: ext4, io, scheduling

I want to delete a huge directory with over 6 million files across over 4000 directories, totaling about 26GB of data.  As I knew this was going to take a while I used `ionice` to set the I/O priority to idle, so I can continue doing other tasks while the files are deleted.

```
time ionice -c3 rm -vrf /tmp/huge-folder
```

However my entire desktop environment is now very sluggish nonetheless, Google chrome takes ages to open new tabs and load pages, sometimes it even takes a while to open a new xterm window.  In summary: I appear to get none of the benefits of reduced I/O priority on the `rm` process.

Inspecting the situation with `iotop` shows that some of the I/O time is spent in the `rm` process with the `idle` I/O priority that I want:

[image: I/O on rm]

But then some other times the I/O time is spent in ext4's journaling process and the software raid process:

[image: I/O on jbd2 and raid]

Note how they are using their own default I/O priority, which is probably the cause of the problem.  `jbd2` even runs at priority `be/3` which is in fact higher priority than the default `be/4` of all my other desktop processes.

[Many other questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=jbd2) ask and answer what `jbd2` is and why it's consuming I/O time, that's not what I'm wondering about.  My question is: Is there a way to truly get the idle I/O scheduling priority in this specific scenario?  Obviously, applying `ionice` to `jbd2` is a crazy idea.

Further setup info: This is on a ext4 filesystem on top of a software raid10 with 3 rotating disks.  ext4 is formatted and mounted using default options (Debian defaults, in case those differ).

Comment: What is the technology of the disks?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro What do you mean by technology? As mentioned, they are rotating disks, more specifically Western Digital model WD3000F9YZ.

Comment: Such a great question and no answers! 

Answer (score 3):

Since I asked this I learned a lot more about how I/O works in the linux kernel and I came do the conclusion that `ionice` just does not work with most write operations.

Read operations are mostly synchronous and can very easily be prioritized.  Presumably this is a lot harder for write operations which are often delayed to a later time (thus asynchronous) in order to be optimized, aggregated and whatnot. I can imagine that transporting and correctly aggregating the niceness information along that way is not easy.

Source: [Some notes on Linux's ionice](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/IoniceNotes).  Note that this source also mentions that `ionice` just does not work with LVM or software RAID, but I have some doubts whether that is still strue (the blog post is a bit dated).

Also see: [ionice does not have any effect on un-synced writes (i.e. normal writes)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480862/ionice-does-not-have-any-effect-on-un-synced-writes-i-e-normal-writes)